# 'break' from a switch, then 'continue' in a loop

Tags: php, control-structure

Is it possible to break from a switch and then continue in a loop?

For example:

```
$numbers= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');

foreach($letters as $letter) {
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        switch($letter) {
           case 'd':
               // So here I want to 'break;' out of the switch, 'break;' out of the
               // $numbers loop, and then 'continue;' in the $letters loop.
               break;
        }
    }

    // Stuff that should be done if the 'letter' is not 'd'.

}
```

Can this be done, and what would the syntax be?

Comment: Amazing, I never knew this, took me ages to realise this was the problem, that a switch's break will affect the outter foreach : (from php site)
" Note that unlike some other languages, the continue statement applies to switch and acts similar to break. If you have a switch inside a loop and wish to continue to the next iteration of the outer loop, use continue 2. "

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use [`break n`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
break 2;
```

---

After clarification, looks like you want [`continue 2;`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: If I was to use "break 2;" would it not continue to execute code after the $numbers loop, but still inside the $letters loop?

Comment: @Drew: I hadn't realized you meant `continue` as a technical term.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of `break`, use `continue 2`.

Comment: The program will go back to the beginning of the numbers loop. This is unique to php. You can view this here =>http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: "    Note: Note that unlike some other languages, the continue statement applies to switch and acts similar to break. If you have a switch inside a loop and wish to continue to the next iteration of the outer loop, use continue 2. "

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a serious necro but... as I arrived here from Google figured I'd save others the confusion.

If he meant breaking out from the switch and just ending the number's loop, then `break 2;` would've been fine. `continue 2;` would just continue the number's loop and keep iterating through it just to be `continue`'d each time.

Ergo, the correct answer ought to be `continue 3;`.

Going by [a comment in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php#96945) continue basically goes to the end of the structure, for switch that's that (will feel the same as break), for loops it'd pick up on the next iteration.

See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dGPpeZ

Example in case above n/a:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!<pre>";

$numbers= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
$letters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');

$i = 0;
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    ++$i;
    echo $letter . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        ++$i;
        switch($letter) {
           case 'd':
               // So here I want to 'break;' out of the switch, 'break;' out of the
               // $numbers loop, and then 'continue;' in the $letters loop.
              continue 3; // go to the end of this switch, numbers loop iteration, letters loop iteration
            break;
           case 'f':
            continue 2; // skip to the end of the switch control AND the current iteration of the number's loop, but still process the letter's loop
            break;
           case 'h':
            // would be more appropriate to break the number's loop
            break 2;

        }
        // Still in the number's loop
        echo " $number ";
    }


    // Stuff that should be done if the 'letter' is not 'd'.
    echo " $i " . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Results:

```
Hello, World!
a
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  11 
b
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  22 
c
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  33 
d
e
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  46 
f
 57 
g
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  68 
h
 70 
i
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  81
```

`continue 2;` not only processes the letter's loop for the letter d but even processes the rest of the number's loop (note that `$i` is both incremented and printed after f). (Which may or may not be desirable...)

Hope that helps anyone else that winds up here first.